# Magento programatically convert quote to order - orders missing in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sales-order, backend, sales-quote

I'm dealing with a strange issue with orders placed with PayPal (most likely IPN problems) as a payment method and I have about 10 orders that are not showing in Magento Admin backend under Sales -> Orders.

To have a better idea of the situation here is the workflow of the issue:
Client adds products to cart -> proceeds to checkout -> selects PayPal -> Places the order -> Client is getting redirected to PayPal where he makes the payment, SUCCESSFULLY gets charged and I get the payment -> Order Confirmation is received with Order number, details, etc...

After that, the customer is redirected back to the website and the products are still in cart! But he paid and got the confirmation.

If I log to PayPal and go to IPN History.. it's full of retrying messages like this (Need to mention that this website worked correctly with PayPal for the past 7 months. 6 days ago the issues started without any changes to PayPal settings)

```
HTTP response code 503 | Delivery status | Retrying | No. of retries | 11
```

Now, if I log into admin backend and go to Sales/Orders -> the order is not there.
If I connect to MySQL and look for the order id (entity id) in sales_flat_order the order is not there. But if I go to sales_flat_quotes, the quote id is there and contains all info (even the reserved_order_id which corresponds with the number from the email - Order #).

1. If someone else encountered this issue, any help is welcome!

**2. Is there a way or what's the best way to convert the quote to order so it can be viewed in backend?**
I have about 15 orders that we're placed through PayPal in the last 6 days and I need to convert the corresponding quotes to orders

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out myself.

1. The not registered order in Magento Backend even if PayPal captured the payment was due to an extension that returned an error after redirection to success page. If someone encounters this type of issue, I highly recommend to switch to sandbox mode and use Mage::log() in Sales/Order.php where convertToOrder is being called.
2. I had to write a script using the same function convertToOrder and validate payment and shipping.

Everything is back to normal now and orders are now showing in backend.

Just thought to write this if someone else will encounter same issue.